# Issue with my PHP Webservice not giving valid JSON

Tags: php, json, web-services

I'm using the Class "mysql2json" to make my Json.

```
<?php
class mysql2json{ 
     static public function getJSON($resultSet,$affectedRecords){ 
        mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
         $numberRows=0; 
         $arrfieldName=array(); 
         $i=0; 
         $json=""; 
        //print("Test"); 
         while ($i < mysql_num_fields($resultSet))  { 
             $meta = mysql_fetch_field($resultSet, $i); 
            if (!$meta) { 
            }else{ 
            $arrfieldName[$i]=$meta->name; 
            } 
            $i++; 
         } 
         $i=0; 
          $json="{\n\"data\": [\n"; 
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultSet, MYSQL_NUM)) { 
            $i++; 
            //print("Ind ".$i."-$affectedRecords<br>"); 
            $json.="{\n"; 
            for($r=0;$r < count($arrfieldName);$r++) { 
                $json.="\"$arrfieldName[$r]\" :    \"$row[$r]\""; 
                if($r < count($arrfieldName)-1){ 
                    $json.=",\n"; 
                }else{ 
                    $json.="\n"; 
                } 
            } 

             if($i!=$affectedRecords){ 
                 $json.="\n},\n"; 
             }else{ 
                 $json.="\n}\n"; 
             } 

        } 
        $json.="]\n};";  
            return $json; 
     } 
}
?>
```

The problem is I'm getting a not valid JSON error in Xcode (iPhone App) and the JSON validator is saying there is an error on line 11 of the results even though line 11 is blank.

Validator: http://jsonlint.com/

Here is a sample URL.

http://leafseed.com/webservice.php?upc=1116102338

Xcode Error:

```
2012-01-11 08:55:46.137 GroceryVine[6476:bf03] -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=10 \"Garbage after JSON\" UserInfo=0x9bbabc0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Garbage after JSON}
```

Validator Error

```
Parse error on line 11:
...."        }    ]};
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: While I still think using `json_encode()` is a *much* better idea, you may want to have a look at the examples in http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php wherein they append `PHP_EOL` within examples, rather than hard-coding `\n`s. Perhaps appending a PHP_EOF would help, if you're really gung-ho on using your current method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Best Solution

I wouldn't bother with this class. Just use the native [`json_encode()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) PHP function as it will give you correctly formatted JSON very easily every time.

For example:

```
$json_arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $json_arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json_arr);
```

A list of other PHP JSON implementations can be found on the [json.org website](http://json.org) <sup>(hint: scroll down)</sup>.

### Direct answer

Looking at your updated question with debug output. Looks like there is an errant semi-colon (`;`) in your output.

Change your last append from

```
$json.="]\n};";
```

to

```
$json.="]\n}";
```

And I think that will fix your issue.

Comment: +1 I was writing the same answer. Don't encore your own JSON; it's a pain for nothing.

Comment: Another thing to remember is that you have to send a header of application/json if you're spitting it right out for a handler. Not really related, I guess, but it's something to consider.

Comment: I was about to write the same thing, It's the technique I've been using since before PHP had a json_encode().  Except I would use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead to get the fieldnames.  It's much less of a pain than the method OP is using.

Comment: Please explain why this answer has received a downvote. This is a correct answer to the OP problem with a solution for their code and a valid suggestion that it be improved using a better method.

Comment: Originally I had used json_encode() except I was having some issues with my output so I tried this class and it *seemed* to be working. Now I'm just going to stick with json_encode() and forget about the class. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

what about `json_encode` function and fetch data separately ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

The **`;`** after the **last curly brace** is wrong

Replacing:

```
    } 
    $json.="]\n};";  
        return $json; 
 }
```

With

```
    } 
    $json.="]\n}";  
        return $json; 
 }
```

should solve your problem.